# Tuple index out of range error with .format(list)

Tags: python, format-string

I have a strange problem I don't get. I have a format string with a lot of fields. I want to supply the content for the fields using a list. The following simple demo below shows the issue:

```py
>>> formatstr = "Hello {}, you are my {} fried since {}"
>>> list = ["John", "best", 2020]
>>> print formatstr.format(list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>>
```

The format string has 3 fields and the list has also 3 elements.
So I don't understand the error message.
Even when I try to address the indexes within the format string:

```py
>>> 
>>> formatstr = "Hello {0:}, you are my {1:} fried since {2:}"
>>> 
>>> print formatstr.format(list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>>
```

Can you please help me? I think I  blocked somewhere in my thinking.
Thanks.

Comment: `formatstr.format(*list)` -- unpack the list

Comment: You seem to be on Python 2 (the print statement `print formatstr.f...` instead of `print(formatstr.form...)` indicates this anyway.) Unless you have a good use-case I recommend learning and using Python 3 as Python 2 is now unmaintained.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the dereference operator did the trick. It's right, that I'm still on Python 2 however due to constraint that the python3 version coming with the distribution is not high enough for an API that we have to use. I try whereever writing code compatible for both version. This example was due to lazyness.